# What does it mean for a call to "spin"

Tags: c++, c, concurrency

What does it mean for a function call to "spin?" Is it the same as blocking?

This is the context I'm referring to:

```
/*
     * Obtain a free channel
     * This call spins till a free channel is obtained
     */
    chNum = _getFreeChannel(&tccNum);
```

Thanks.

Comment: something like `Channel c = getFreeChannel(); while(c == NULL) c = getFreeChannel();`

Comment: ["You are not expected to understand this."](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/odd.html)

Comment: It's a technique for speeding up the cooling fan on your computer:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To loop, basically. What a spinning function does is busy-waiting with a loop.

Answer (score 6):

A *spin* is a concurrency technique. Essentially the function loops until the desired condition is met.

It can be computationally expensive if the spin time is large, but can be preferable to wait and notification idioms (for which there is a set-up overhead) if the expected spin time is very small with low variance.

Answer (score 3):

When a Function spins,  it is typically checking some condition (like a variable) over and over in a tight loop until it becomes some interesting value.  It then continues running once the condition is met.